# How to get Context in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

```
fun createListItem(itemIndex: Int) {
    Padding(left = 8.dp, right = 8.dp, top = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp) {
        FlexRow(crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.Center) {
            expanded(1.0f) {
                Text("Item $itemIndex")
            }
            inflexible {
                Button(
                    "Button $itemIndex",
                    style = ContainedButtonStyle(),
                    onClick = {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this@MainActivity,
                            "Item name $itemIndex",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try to make Toast in a normal way. but I got the error I tried a lot of multiples source but failed.

Comment: You might want to explain exactly what your problem was. I have used `Toast` in `onClick` handlers in Compose without a problem. If you were getting a compile error, please provide the complete details of the error. If you were getting a runtime error, please edit your question and post the stack trace.

Comment: FYI: while the answers below are valid, the compose team now recommends using `Snackbar` over `Toast` in Compose: https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1614352257404200?thread_ts=1614333574.353800&cid=CJLTWPH7S.

Answer (score 357, accepted):

**Update March 2021:** The previous answer has been deprecated. You should now use:

```
val context = LocalContext.current
```

---

#### Previous answer for reference:

You can access to context with define `ambientContext`.

**Example:**

```
val context = ContextAmbient.current
```

Comment: compose is declarative & as a tree, so if you have complex trees and you need some state that could not provided from root component, you can use ambient or memo

Comment: Is there any doc that explains the use of this unaryPlus operator? I can't find anything solid to understand what it is and how to use it @Raka

Comment: When I add val context = +ambient(ContextAmbient) to Clickable then get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Composition requires an active composition context

Comment: please show your code (by gist.github.com) @AlexZezekalo

Comment: @RakaAdiNugroho I found out that I used a wrong place for getting context: firstly I wrote <code>val context = +ambient(ContextAmbient)<code> inside *Clickable* and it was the reason of that exception. Then I put this line out of the *Clickable* to the head of the function and everything became Ok. My fault.

Comment: `LocalContext.current` can not be used in coroutine scope. This happens typically, when Android forces you to do something in a different thread, than the UI thread.

Comment: I haven't seen this explicitly stated, but it appears Ambient has been removed/rename something else?

I found this:
https://lcdsmao.dev/jetpack-compose-what-is-the-difference-between-ambient-and-static-ambient/

describing what it was.

This seems related:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-runtime

Renamed Ambients to match the Ambient -> CompositionLocal rename. Ambients used to be named AmbientFoo, now CompositionLocals are named LocalFoo. (I2d55d)

I found ambients in old sample code:
https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Jetchat

Answer (score 82):

`ContextAmbient` and `AmbientContext` has been deprecated.

You can replace them with `LocalContext`

**Example:**

```
val context = LocalContext.current
```

Comment: How can I use this `val context = LocalContext.current` as a global variable in my Activity?

Comment: @gauravkumar I think the most you can do is declaring it as the first line in `setContent` method because it only works inside composable function. If you need a context outside `setContent`, just use `this`.

Comment: Android changes faster than the speed of light.. I have never used ContextAmbient and AmbientContext in my life.

Answer (score 36):

<strike>`ContextAmbient.current`</strike> is deprecated as of `alpha-09`.

<strike>`AmbientContext.current`</strike> is deprecated. I think as of `alpha-11`.

`LocalContext.current` is how you get the context in a composable now.

Answer (score 33):

The way to do this has been updated.  It's now:

```kotlin
val context = LocalContext.current
```

[LocalContext docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#localcontext)

Answer (score 31):

`ContextAmbient` and `AmbientContext` is deprecated

**Update**

Now Jetpack way to do this has been updated. It's now:

```
val context = LocalContext.current
```

Comment: What about Application context?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Once you have the local context, context.getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 31):

> LocalContext.current - is the right approach. But the problem is you
> can't use LocalContext.current inside @Composable function

You need to create separate function to use Context

**Sample code**

```
@Composable
fun DoneButton() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Button(onClick = { showToast(context, "Button clicked")}) {
        Text(name = "Done")
    }
}

fun showToast(context: Context, msg: String) {
    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Answer (score 14):

`ContextAmbient.current` has been deprecated, use `val context = LocalContext.current` instead.

Answer (score 9):

Some useful if you need get context as Activity from last Android Studio template:

```
val view = LocalView.current
(view.context as Activity).<activity method>
```

Better solution

```
fun Context.getActivity(): Activity? = when (this) {
    is Activity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.getActivity()
    else -> null
}

val activity = LocalContext.current.getActivity()
```

Comment: It is not safe as the context may not be an activity.

Comment: @EmadRazavi Agree, I updated my answer

Answer (score 6):

For getting context in jetpack compose:

```
val context = ContextAmbient.current
```

> Working on 0.1.0-dev14

How to use it in **TOAST**:

```
@Composable
fun cardViewImplementer(item: Int) {
   val context = ContextAmbient.current
   Card(
     shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
     modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
   ) {
     Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .drawShadow(5.dp)
            .clickable(onClick = {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked $item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }), children = {

        })
}
```

For accessing the **Resource**:

```
Text("Read this string: "+context.getString(R.string.name))
```

Answer (score 5):

Issues with `compose_version = '1.0.0-alpha12'` ?  `AmbientContext` is now `LocalContext`

Answer (score 2):

```
val context = LocalContext.current
Toast.makeText(context,"Hello Compose",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LocalUriHandler`:

```
val handler = LocalUriHandler.currenthandler 

Button( 
    onClick = { handler.openUri("https://www.stackoverflow.com") } 
) {    
     Text("Open") 
}
```