# How to request permissions in Compose application?

Tags: android, android-permissions, mobile-development, android-jetpack-compose

I was trying to find out how to request permissions in Jetpack Compose. Found [an article in official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#request-permission), but I couldn't figure out how to use it in my case; there's also [an answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64080907/9645340), but I simply couldn't understand it.

I will appreciate if you show some of your examples with explanation, or help me understand the code from the answer that I mentioned.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I understood it.

You need to implement this composable and use it when you need to use a feature that needs the permissions: you pass in an array of `permissions`, a `requestCode` (*any* `Int`), and two lambdas with composables: `onGranted`, which is used when the permissions were granted, and `onDenied` composable in the other case.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PermissionsRequest(
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    requestCode: Int,
    onGranted: @Composable () -> Unit,
    onDenied: @Composable () -> Unit,
    onDeniedPermanently: (@Composable () -> Unit)? = null,
    rational: (@Composable () -> Unit)? = null,
    awaitResult: (@Composable () -> Unit)? = null,
) {
    val permissionHandler = AmbientPermissionHandler.current
    val (permissionResult, setPermissionResult) = remember(permissions) {
        mutableStateOf<PermissionResult?>(null)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        setPermissionResult(permissionHandler.requestPermissions(requestCode, permissions))
    }

    when (permissionResult) {
        is PermissionResult.PermissionGranted -> onGranted()
        is PermissionResult.PermissionDenied -> onDenied()
        is PermissionResult.PermissionDeniedPermanently -> onDeniedPermanently?.invoke()
        is PermissionResult.ShowRational -> rational?.invoke()
        null -> awaitResult?.invoke()
    }
}
```

Also you need to implement an ambient. As I understand it, it is used to pass the value down the composables children. In our case `AmbientPermissionHandler` is going to be passed with its value — `PermissionHandler` — to the `PermissionsRequest` from `Providers` composable.

```kotlin
val AmbientPermissionHandler = ambientOf<PermissionHandler>()
```

The `PermissionHandler` implementation that would be passed to `PermissionRequest` composable as an `AmbientPermissionHandler` using `Providers`.

```kotlin
class PermissionHandler(private val context: AppCompatActivity) {
    suspend fun requestPermissions(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>
    ): PermissionResult {
        return PermissionManager.requestPermissions(context, requestCode, *permissions)
    }
}
```

And then you use it like this:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val permissionHandler = PermissionHandler(this)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            Providers(
                AmbientPermissionHandler provides permissionHandler
            ) {
                PermissionsRequest(
                    permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS),
                    requestCode = PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                    onGranted = { /* Here goes the composables when the permission is granted */ },
                    onDenied = { /* Is used when the permission is denied */ }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Initialize `PermissionHandler` in `MainActivity` and then provide it in `Providers` inside the `setContent`.

To use `PermissionManager` and `LaunchedEffect` you need those dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.sagar:coroutinespermission:2.0.3'
implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.0.0-alpha11'
```

And thanks to [2jan222](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9957384/2jan222) for the [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64080907/9645340).

Answer (score 1):

you don't need any additional library for request permission

```
//define permission in composable fun
val getPermission = rememberLauncherForActivityResult( 
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
) { isGranted ->
    if (isGranted) {
       //permission accepted do somthing
    } else {
       //permission not accepted show message
    }
}
//i used SideEffect to launch permission request when screen recomposed
//you can call it inside a button click without SideEffect
SideEffect {
    getPermission.launch(Manifest.permission.YOUR_PERMISSION_REQEUST)
}
```

and if you wanted to request multiple permission use this:

```
ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it was quite simple, I just made a composable and called it in my MainActivity like this, in setContent:

```
 checkNotificationPolicyAccess(notificationManager, this)
```

Basically, if the permission is not granted, I show a Dialog.

```
@Composable
fun checkNotificationPolicyAccess(
    notificationManager: NotificationManager,
    context: Context
): Boolean {
    if (notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted) {
        return true
    } else {
        NotificationPolicyPermissionDialog(context)
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. I need to request a permission — a READ_SMS permission in my case — and then to handle a request code callback, so I can show either a list of SMS messages, if the permission granted, or a text saying that they are not supported without a permission.