# What is the best approach to handle permissions requests?

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I have implemented `accompanist` permission, but as far as I know it is deprecated.
What is the best new approach?
My actual code:

```
    val notificationPermissionState: PermissionState
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        notificationPermissionState = rememberPermissionState(
            Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
        )

[...]
onClick {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                        notificationPermissionState.launchPermissionRequest()
    }
                    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73913165/6321878

Comment: "I have implemented accompanist permission, but as far as I know it is deprecated" - no it isn't. What makes you think it is deprecated?

Comment: I'm changing entire accompanist libraries to androidx.compose approach. However, I see that permissions from accompanist is not deprecated yet. @MalikBilal thanks for your answer, but if there is not official better approach I will stay with accompanist for a while.