NavController.onGraphCreated throws java.lang.IllegalStateException
I am using the latest version of the Android Compose navigation library (2.8.0-beta04).
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.8.0-beta04"
}

When I run the app locally and trough internal testing everything works fine. However I see this crash happening to a few users and different devices/os levels.
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated (NavController.kt:309)
  at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph (NavController.kt:309)
  at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph (NavController.kt:309)
  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost (NavHost.kt:15)
  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost (NavHost.kt:2)
  at com.mackslydev.swimwatch.navigation.SwimwatchNavGraphKt.RootNavGraph (SwimwatchNavGraph.kt:198)
  at com.mackslydev.swimwatch.MainActivity$onCreate$1$2$2$1.invoke (MainActivity.kt:75)
  at com.mackslydev.swimwatch.MainActivity$onCreate$1$2$2$1.invoke (MainActivity.kt:75)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.a (CompositionLocal.kt:19)
  at com.mackslydev.swimwatch.MainActivity$onCreate$1$2$2.invoke (MainActivity.kt:59)
  at com.mackslydev.swimwatch.MainActivity$onCreate$1$2$2.invoke (MainActivity.kt:59)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at com.mackslydev.swimwatch.MainActivity$onCreate$1$2.invoke (MainActivity.kt:158)
  at com.mackslydev.swimwatch.MainActivity$onCreate$1$2.invoke (MainActivity.kt:158)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.a (CompositionLocal.kt:19)
  at androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle (Text.kt:78)
  at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke (MaterialTheme.kt:32)
  at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke (MaterialTheme.kt:32)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.b (CompositionLocal.kt:19)
  at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme (MaterialTheme.kt:267)
  at com.mackslydev.swimwatch.ui.theme.ThemeKt.SwimWatchTheme (Theme.kt:238)
  at com.mackslydev.swimwatch.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke (MainActivity.kt:151)
  at com.mackslydev.swimwatch.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke (MainActivity.kt:151)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.a (ComposeView.android.kt:56)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke (ComposeView.android.kt:28)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke (ComposeView.android.kt:28)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.b (CompositionLocal.kt:19)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals (CompositionLocals.kt:395)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke (AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:32)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke (AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:32)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.b (CompositionLocal.kt:19)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals (AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:592)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke (Wrapper.android.kt:32)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke (Wrapper.android.kt:32)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.a (CompositionLocal.kt:19)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke (Wrapper.android.kt:185)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke (Wrapper.android.kt:185)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke (ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:53)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable (ActualJvm.jvm.kt:1)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose (Composer.kt:201)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release (ComposerImpl.java:45)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent (Composition.kt:45)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release (Recomposer.kt:25)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeInitial (Composition.kt:11)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent (Composition.kt:11)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke (Wrapper.android.kt:57)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke (Wrapper.android.kt:57)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable (AndroidComposeView.android.kt)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent (Wrapper.android.kt:1)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged (Wrapper.android.kt:1)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent (LifecycleRegistry.jvm.kt:23)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver (LifecycleRegistry.jvm.kt:228)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke (Wrapper.android.kt:25)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke (Wrapper.android.kt:25)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow (AndroidComposeView.android.kt:125)
  at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow (View.java:21785)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3677)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3684)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3684)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3684)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3684)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:3947)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:3225)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:11119)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1938)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1946)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:1226)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:1089)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1892)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:971)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:206)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:296)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:9159)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:591)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1018)

I tried to reproduce the issue by building release builds locally and test it on production. However, I cannot reproduce it. Everything seems to work totally fine and no crash is happening. Can anyone help me?
The NavHost is created inside a Composable called RootNavGraph as follows. I think this is where it crashes.
@Composable
fun RootNavGraph(
  navController: NavHostController,
  stopwatchViewModel: StopwatchViewModel,
  onToggleDrawer: () -> Unit
) {
   NavHost(
     navController = navController,
     startDestination = Stopwatch,
     modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)) {
  // composables
}

The Stopwatch destination is created like described in the docs of the navigation library.
@Serializable
object Stopwatch

As suggested, I tried to locate SwimwatchNavGraph.kt:198. However this line doesn't exist inside my file. I pasted the stacktrace in the stacktrace analyzer embedded in Android studio. When I pressed the SwimatchNavGraph.kt:198.
This showed as inline function body.
/**
* Retrieves a registered [Navigator] using the name provided by the
* [Navigator.Name annotation][Navigator.Name].
*
* @throws IllegalStateException if the Navigator has not been added
*/
@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
public inline operator fun <T : Navigator<out NavDestination>> NavigatorProvider.get(clazz: KClass<T>): T = getNavigator(clazz.java)

This was showed as called site.
animatedComposable<SavedTimeDetail> {
    val id = it.toRoute<SavedTimeDetail>().stopwatchId

    SavedTimesDetailScreen(id) {
        navController.navigateUp()
    }
}

MainActivity.kt:75 points towards this piece of code
DisposableEffect(Unit) {
window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
onDispose {
    window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
} <-- here
}


It would help if you can include the relevant code for this issue.

I added the code snippet.

Please also share the code showing the SwimwatchNavGraph.kt:198. This is the origin of the crash.

I added more code snippets to clarify SwimwatchNavGraph.kt:198

I am not sure if addFlags or clearFlags will work in Jetpack Compose properly, have you tried the Jetpack equivalent? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69039723/is-there-a-jetpack-compose-equivalent-for-androidkeepscreenon-to-keep-screen-al

I have tested it, and it does work properly in this implementation. Since this Disposable block is located at the root level of the app.
