# Classifier 'Context' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-context

Here is my code

```
fun Uri.getOriginalFileName(context: Context): String? {
    return context.contentResolver.query(this, null, null, null, null)?.use {
        val nameColumnIndex = it.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
        it.moveToFirst()
        it.getString(nameColumnIndex)
    }
}


@Composable
fun AppNotice() {
    
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.type = "*/*"; ///
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
                activityResult ->   if (activityResult.resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Log.d("appDebug", "oky")
                var uri = intent.getData()
                val name: String? = uri?.getOriginalFileName(Context)
                Log.d("seeFile", "$name")
                 }

            else {
                Log.d("appDebug", "Denied")
            }
Button(onClick={launcher.launch(intent)})
{Text("Button")}
            }
```

Context is a class then how to know what method will i need in this line/context `name: String? = uri?.getOriginalFileName(Context)`

I went to adroid.dev page but found a huge page and cant figure out what i need since saw only few uri permission related stuffs.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58743541/9636037) help?

Comment: Is `getOriginalFileName` a function you have created?

Comment: Sorry paste prolem. I am updaing it @Abhimanyu

Comment: Well i got your point@RichardOnslowRoper. Do you know of any site which is of college level? I tried Stackover Chat but thhere is reputation requirement......

Comment: Thanks. So i should use ```val context = LocalContext.current``` LocalContext.current.

Comment: Btw on a side note, on this issue i wasted hours, i think. Why not post my problem if someone kind & alike minded who went through the same can help me and give importance/value to his as well as others time. No need to refigure out things which which has already been figured.

Comment: "Why not post my problem if someone kind & alike minded who went through the same can help me *within in a minute* and ........"*